# Canvas size in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have this code in my project, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/89wgk/

This is my code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="188" height="200"></canvas>
     var rectWidth = 110;
     var rectHeight = 110;
     var rectX = 10;
     var rectY = 25;
```

When I put the mouse in curved rectangle starts the shadow, but I want that to happen when I put the mouse over the reeds (rectangle) and not within the `canvas`.

I wonder how do I run the shadow so when I move the mouse over the rectangle?

Comment: You cannot use mouse events on shapes within a canvas (as the canvas is effectively just an image) The way I've gone about doing things like this before is to use the relative mouse position on the page and position of the canvas, to workout the mouse's canvas coordinates. This can then be used to work out when you mouse over a specific area.

Comment: Hey Alien how i can convert my code into svg?

Comment: @AlienArrays, Sure you can do this in canvas! Just use context.isPointInPath to hit-test any path that you've drawn.

Comment: @AlienArrays Sure you can do transforms (including scaling) in canvas.  Just use context.scale.  BTW, I like+use both Canvas and  SVG...just saying that since the questions was about Canvas that Canvas can solve this question. :)

Comment: Ok MarkE now, how i will implement this in my code?

Comment: I posted an answer showing my solution using html5 Canvas.  BTW, depending on your design requirements SVG is a fine solution also.  SVG are actual DOM elements (you can position them on the page and they generate their own events).  Canvas drawings are just pixels painted on a canvas (canvas drawings don't generate their own events but drawing on the canvas is really fast--great for animation).  Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

- create a function that draws the arc shape because it must be redrawn often
- listen for mouseMove events on the canvas
- test whether the mouse is inside the arc with context.isPointInside(mouseX,mouseY)
- redraw the arc with/without the shadow based on if the mouse is inside the arc

**Have Fun!**

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/64BHx/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var w = 110;
    var h = 110;
    var x = 10;
    var y = 25;

    var isShadowed=false;

    context.strokeStyle="#FF2A2A";
    context.shadowBlur = 20;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 5;
    context.shadowOffsetY = 5;


    context.globalAlpha=.250;
    context.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
    context.globalAlpha=1.00;

    function draw(){

        // clear the canvas
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // save the context state
        context.save();

        // set/clear the shadow based on isShadowed
        context.shadowColor= isShadowed ? '#7FD4FF' : "#FFFFFF";

        // draw the arc shape
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x,y);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(x+w-2,y+2,x+w,y+h);
        context.lineTo(x+w-35,y+h);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(x+w-2-35,y+2+35,x,y+35);
        context.lineTo(x,y);
        context.fillStyle="red";
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

        // restore the context state
        context.restore();
    }

    // testing: display if mouse is in/out of arc shape
    var $status=$("#status");

    // listen for mousemove events
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

    // handle mousemove events
    function handleMouseMove(e){

        // we alone are using mousemove events
        e.preventDefault();

        // get current mouse X/Y
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // hit test if mouse is inside the arc shape
        var isInside=context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY);
        $status.text("Is mouse inside: "+isInside);

        // don't redraw unless needed
        if(isInside && isShadowed){return;}
        if(!isInside && !isShadowed){return;}

        // change the shadow and redraw
        isShadowed=isInside;
        draw();
    }


    // start by drawing the unshadowed arc
    draw();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="status">Status</p><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have one question now, and if I like to put [cursor:pointer] when i put the mouse inside de draw?!

Comment: This will change the cursor to pointer: $("#canvas").css("cursor", "pointer"); This will change the cursor pointer back to its default arrow: $("#canvas").css("cursor", "default"); So, inside the draw() function if isShadowed set the cursor to pointer and if !isShadowed then reset the cursor back to the default arrow. Cheers!